# Emacs 23: Selection not highlighted

Tags: emacs, highlighting, region

I installed Ubuntu 10.04, and with it came Emacs 23. If I want to select text in Emacs, that works perfectly fine except the fact that the region is not highlighted.

However, this only happens, if I try to make a region using the keyboard. If I select something with the mouse, it is highlighted as usual.

Does anybody know, why the region is not highlighted and how to fix that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is the option  'Options->Active Region Highlighting' set?

You may want to set

```
(transient-mark-mode t)
```

in `~/.emacs` or other init files as well.

Comment: It's weird: 'Options->Active Region Highlightning' was set, so I clicked it away.

I'm no Emacs (and not at all an Emacs List) expert, but after inserting the line `(transient-mark-mode)` into my `~/.emacs`, it worked. Do you know, what's happening there?

Comment: I have been using that toggle in my `~/.emacs` for this reason for many years -- the manual documents it just fine.   I use the interactive options less, so maybe 'Active Region Highlighting' tickles something else.

Comment: BTW, temporary-transient-mark-mode is much better than transient-mark-mode.  This lets you setup a transient mark by pressing C-SPC C-SPC instead of just C-SPC. Much less intrusive.  (Oh, and it's on by default, so no config required.)